# Using NLog in multithreaded environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, multithreading, nlog

I have a WPF application, which starts a background worker i.e. Asp.Net Core Web API server.

I want to log all the events in a single log file. 
**NOTE: I want ASP.net core framework logging from Microsoft too.**
I am using Nlog(for the first time) for this.

Code:

**nlog.config file:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal.txt">


  <!-- define various log targets -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="c:\temp\TestSimLogs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
                 layout="${longdate}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}" concurrentWrites="true" keepFileOpen="true"/>

    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile" fileName="c:\temp\TestSimLogs\nlog-own-${shortdate}.log"
              layout="${longdate}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}" concurrentWrites="true" keepFileOpen="true"/>

    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**In WPFfile.cs:**

> References: Nlog

```
private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

 //lots of code

 private void Button_StartServer(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Info($"Started Server in mode {mode}");  

            // logic
            WebSocket_Worker.RunWorkerAsync("WS begin");
            WebAPI_Worker.RunWorkerAsync("WebAPI begin");

            Status = $"Server Started in mode {mode}";
        }
```

**In Asp.Net Core :**

> References: Nlog.Extensions.Logging, Nlog.Web.AspNetCore

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddNLog();
            app.AddNLogWeb();
            env.ConfigureNLog("./../../nlog.config");     
            app.UseMiddleware_Authorization();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Issue:
The log file is not as expected. Only asp.net core logs are shown in the log file.

Answer (score 1):

Huh! 
Silly mistake, I didn't set "Copy To Output Directory" to  "Copy Always" in nlog.config file.